# Cannot get Xcode SCM to work with Gitolite based server

Tags: xcode, git, gitolite

For whatever reason, I cannot get the built-in source control tools in Xcode 4.1 to work with the git repository I have setup on my server.  The server is setup to use Gitolite.

Everything works fine from the command line.  I can add the remote, push, pull, and then clone out again.  I can also access Github in Xcode just fine.

Has anyone been successful getting these two tools to work together?
Any idea how I can debug this (I have no idea what Xcode is doing behind the scenes)?

The only thing that has stood out to me is that Xcode wants to include a top-level folder when accessing the repository, i.e.: `git@my-server.com:folder/repository-name.git` and Gitolite doesn't want you to do that.  It wants: `git@my-server.com:repository-name.git`

Answer (score 1):

I have a Gitolite 2.0.3 server running on Ubuntu 11.10, and I am able to use with the built-in SCM integration in Xcode 4.2 running on Snow Leopard.

To see log information about commits and other SCM operations, go to the Xcode log navigator (speech bubble icon in the left column, or select View > Navigators > Show Log Navigator, or press Cmd-9). The log navigator has filters to show only error messages. That should give you more information about what's going on.

One thing that stands out for me in your question is that when using Gitolite, I never use the `.git` suffix on the client went entering the git URI. Try omitting that and see if that makes any difference when working in Xcode. For example, I have git repositories on the server in folders like `~gitolite/repositories/project1.git` or `~gitolite/repositories/apps/ios/project2.git`, but when I am on the client, the git URIs look like: `ssh://gitolite@myserver.com:12345/project1`, or `ssh://gitolite@myserver.com:12345/apps/ios/project2`.